# Passing Exceptions up the stack in Dart from async to sync methods

Tags: dart, error-handling, try-catch

So, coming from Javascript world, I can handle exceptions that are thrown however deep down the stack. Doing the same in Dart doesn't work. I'm not sure how to pass exceptions up, to be handled at the root of the stack.

```dart
willThrow() async {
    throw Exception('Im an exception');
}

init() async {
    final illNeverExist = await willThrow();
    print(illNeverExist);
}

main() {
  try {
    init();
  } catch(err) {
    print(err);
  }
}
```

^^^ This totally works in javascript.

In 'init', even if I wrap that in a try catch, and throw that error, I always get an uncaught exception.

```dart
init() async {
    try {
        final illNeverExist = await willThrow();
        print(illNeverExist);
    } catch(err) {
        throw err
    }
}
```

How do you pass async exceptions up the stack in dart?!

Comment: You need to make `main` `async` and use `await init();` (or directly use `Future.catchError`).

Comment: You're right! That worked. Son of a b. Thank you! If that was an answer, I'd of marked it as such!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `try`-`catch` block in your `main` function doesn't wait for your asynchronous `init` function to complete.  Consequently, when `init` does complete, its exception will no longer be caught.

You can fix this by making `main` `async` and using `await init();`, or you can use `Future.catchError` to directly register an error callback on the returned `Future`.